# firebase key value return undefined

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to display list of event with a delete button and can only be deleted by the event creator. but when i try to delete it, it deletes all other event with it. I am actually trying to delete by Key Value from firebase-realtime-database, but the `event.id` return as undefined, i guess it delete the whole folder instead.

My home.html, display data and can directly delete from this page

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let event of eventList$ | async">
  <ion-item>
    <h4>{{event.name}}</h4>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <h4>{{event.location}}</h4>

    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="checkUser(event)">
        <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
      </button>
  </ion-buttons>
  </ion-item>

</ion-card>
```

My home.ts

```
this.database.list<EventModels>('event-list').valueChanges().subscribe((eventData) => { 

  }, (err)=>{
 console.log("Error while retrieving event details : ", err);
  }); 

  this.eventListRef$ = this.database.list<EventModels>('event-list');
  this.eventList$ = this.eventListRef$.valueChanges();

checkUser(event: EventModels) {
  console.log(event.id, event.name);
  if(firebase.auth().currentUser.email == event.creator) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Confirm Delete.',
      message: 'You cannot recover this event once it is deleted.',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Yes',
          role: 'destructive',
          handler: () => {
            this.eventListRef$.remove(event.id);
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel'
        }
      ]
    }).present();
  } else{
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Could Not Delete Event!',
      subTitle: 'This event does not belong to you.',
      buttons: ['Dismiss']
    });
    alert.present();
  }
}
```

My EventModels, events.ts in models folder

```
export interface EventModels {
  id?: string;
  creator: any;
  name: string;
  location: string;
  start: any;
  end: any;
  time: any;
}
```

I have tried to use `$key?: String` but it still returned undefined

Creating event

```
addEvent = {} as EventModels;
eventRef$: AngularFireList<EventModels>;

  this.eventRef$ = this.database.list('event-list');

  save(addEvent: EventModels){
    this.eventRef$.push({
      creator: firebase.auth().currentUser.email,
      name: this.addEvent.name,
      location: this.addEvent.location,
      start: this.addEvent.start,
      end: this.addEvent.end,
      time: this.addEvent.time,
    });

    this.addEvent = {} as EventModels;

    this.navCtrl.pop()
  }
```

Comment: You should share how `eventList$` is created. Are you using `snapshotChanges()` and adding key/id to each `EventModels` object? Is `id` explicitly included in every `EventModels` object in your database?

Comment: I have update it, I don't know how to implement that, I am pretty new to ionic, and the tutorial that I follow are kinda outdated.

Comment: If `console.log()` the value of `eventData` in the `subscribe()` are you seeing an `id` for each item in the array/stream? Can you share how a child item in `event-list` of your Firebase RTDB looks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing how `eventList$` in `home.ts` is created, instead using [snapshotChanges()](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#snapshotchanges) to extract the `key` of each item and assigning to the `id` property:

```
// ...

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

this.eventListRef$ = this.database.list<EventModels>('event-list');
this.eventList$ = this.eventListRef$.snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
    map(changes => 
      changes.map(c => ({ id: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
    )
  );
```

It looks like `id` may not be a property that exists for each child in your `event-list` RTDB node. `snapshotChanges()` exposes metadata such as the `key` for each object as well as the object values that can be used to create the complete `EventModels` object for each item.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: this really help! I am following Paul Halliday's tutorial, he uses `$key: string,` in the models, but I don't really know why mines not working. thank you very much